# Reset picturebox to default image

Tags: vb.net

I have a picturebox. I set the default image to a picture with some word. So it embed in the textbox. So I load this picturebox using code. The when I click on Reset button, I will dispose the image that been hold. So how to set back the default image after I dispose it?

Comment: Store the default Image in a Bitmap Field object. Set this Bitmap as a PictureBox.Image when needed. I have no idea what *I set the default image to a picture with some word* and *So it embed in the textbox* mean.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sqlite. Please remove the tag or edit your question to show relationship to sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like the following code?

```
pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox1.InitialImage
```